# Search in Gmail only threads with N responses

Tags: gmail, search

Can I search only threads with N responses in Gmail?

Something like:

```
query mails:5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, we don't have a search operator for # of responses, and I can't think of a workaround.

Comment: Something simpler like searching threads with responses (N >= 2) also impossible?